# Calculating the average in row wise using PySpark, without using udf

Tags: pyspark

## Creat a function that that do the following without using UDF only pyspark code:

1. takes as input pyspark dataFrame and list of values = ['column1', 'column2']

```
+--+-------+--------+
|id|column1 |column2|
+--+-------+--------+
|1 |  2.0  |  3.0  |
|2 |  1.0  |  3.0  |
|3 | -1.0  |  3.0  |
|4 | -1.0  | -1.0  |
+--+-------+-------+
```

2. creat a column that count number for columns in values that not contain -1

```
+--+-------+--------+-----+
|id|column1 |column2|count|
+--+-------+--------+-----+
|1 |  2.0  |  3.0  |  2  |
|2 |  1.0  |  3.0  |  2  |
|3 | -1.0  |  3.0  |  1  |
|4 | -1.0  | -1.0  |  0  |
+--+-------+-------+-----+
```

3. creat a column that sum number for columns in values that not contain -1

```
+--+-------+--------+-----+------+
|id|column1 |column2|count|sum   |
+--+-------+--------+-----+------+
|1 |  2.0  |  3.0  |  2  |  5.0 |
|2 |  1.0  |  3.0  |  2  |  4.0 |
|3 | -1.0  |  3.0  |  1  |  3.0 |
|4 | -1.0  | -1.0  |  0  |  0.0 |
+--+-------+-------+-----+------+
```

4. creat a column that average number for columns in values that not contain -1

```
+--+-------+--------+-----+------+------+
|id|column1 |column2|count|sum   |avg   |
+--+-------+--------+-----+------+------+
|1 |  2.0  |  3.0  |  2  |  5.0 |  2.5 |
|2 |  1.0  |  3.0  |  2  |  4.0 |  2.0 |
|3 | -1.0  |  3.0  |  1  |  3.0 |  3.0 |
|4 | -1.0  | -1.0  |  0  |  0.0 |  0.0 |
+--+-------+-------+-----+------+------+
```

I already managed to do it using udf

```
def average_columns(columns: list) -> float:
    """
    This function calculates the average conflict score between the different deduplication methods.

    Parameters
    ----------
    values : list
        The list of column names to be compared.

    Returns
    -------
    float
        The average conflict score.
    """
    values = [val for val in columns if val != -1]
    return sum(values) / len(values) if values else float(0)

average_columns_udf = F.udf(avg_conflict, T.FloatType())
```

But i want to do it using only PySpark functions
this code is a sudo code its not working

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
pyspark.sql.functions as F

values = ['column1', 'column2']

def average_columns(df: DataFrame,
                    values: list): -> DataFrame
    return df.withColumn('count', F.sum(F.when(F.col(value) != -1, 1).otherwise(0)) for value in values) \
             .withColumn('sum', F.sum(F.when(F.col(value) != -1, F.col(value)).otherwise(0)) for value in values) \
             .withColumn('avg', F.col('sum') / F.col('count'))
```

Answer (score 0):

High order function will help. Code and logic below

```
new =(df.withColumn('ABCD', array(*[x for x in df.columns if x!='id']))#Create an array
      .withColumn('count', expr("aggregate(transform(ABCD, (c,i)-> cast(c=='-1' as int)),0, (j,k)-> j+k )" ))#Find where there is -1 using transform, cast bool to integer and sum
      .withColumn('sum', expr("aggregate(ABCD, cast(0 as bigint), (x,y)->x+y)"))#Sum elements in a list
      .withColumn('avg', col('sum')/size(col('ABCD')))#Sum/over count of ABCD
      
     ).show()

new.show()

+---+-------+-------+--------+-----+---+----+
| id|column1|column2|    ABCD|count|sum| avg|
+---+-------+-------+--------+-----+---+----+
|  1|      2|      3|  [2, 3]|    0|  5| 2.5|
|  2|      1|      3|  [1, 3]|    0|  4| 2.0|
|  3|     -1|      3| [-1, 3]|    1|  2| 1.0|
|  4|     -1|     -1|[-1, -1]|    2| -2|-1.0|
+---+-------+-------+--------+-----+---+----+
```